# Writing a two-body operator in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, second-quantization

I have the following two-body operator
$$ \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq N} w(x_i-x_j)$$
acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^-_N=\bigwedge^NL^2(\Lambda)$, which describes the interaction between $N$ fermions in a $d$-dimensional cube $\Lambda=[0,L]^d$ with periodic boundary conditions.

I want to write this operator in second quantization and I am not really sure on how to do this. My understanding is, that I need an ONB $(a_\alpha)$ which in my case would be plane waves of the form $e^{ikx}$ and that it should look like the following:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{p,q,r,s}\left\langle u_p \otimes u_q, \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq N} w(x_i-x_j) u_r \otimes u_s\right\rangle a^*(u_p)a^*(u_q)a(u_r)a(u_s)$$

Is this correct and is there a way of computing it?

Comment: What is the question? "Is this correct?" is off-topic. Have you checked *any* book on second quantization/many-body physics?

Comment: Of course I have! I am sorry if you think of this as a stupid question... I just don't really know how to deal with this

Comment: If you could recommend a good book for this topic i would also be very greatful

Comment: I don't think it is a stupid question. I said it is an off-topic question! Have you checked the lecture notes of Solovej, for example? IIRC there it is proven how you can write a two-body operator in SQ -  but this should be done really in any book on many-body theory.

Comment: I understand! What I used were the lecture notes of a Professor at my university I found online. A proper textbook sounds like a better idea and I will definitely check out the lecture notes of solovej